# Compiling idl files with CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, corba, idl

I have a directory with idls:

```
./idl/1.idl
./idl/2.idl
./idl/3.idl
 ...
```

How can I compile this idls with CMake into .cpp and .h files?

Comment: Which Orb are you using? MICO, ORBIX?

Comment: Orbacus – embeddable C++ CORBA ORB

Comment: For orbacus I recommend contacting the commercial support.